# Scala getClass ponderings

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have a Scala list for which I derive the following pair of outputs (Scala 2.10):

```
println(myList.getClass)`
// class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

println(myList) 
// List(1, 2, 3,....)
```

Could you please explain:

1. What is the meaning of $colon$colon
2. Why doesn't the output derived from getClass indicate this is a List, not just some collection?

Comment: @gabriele, while the intention is good, your edit of this question isn't good - look at the awkward numbering inside the bullets that you created. also why the extra backtick? ... can you please correct or revise to your liking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `$colon$colon` is the encoding in a JVM-friendly (but not human-friendly) of the class `::`. Recall that an empty list is the singleton `Nil`, and that a non-empty list is a `::` (read "cons") with a head (which is an element) and a tail (which is again a list).
A non-empty list is therefore always an instance of this class `::`. But the compiler renames it to `$colon$colon` for the JVM to be happy.

I'm not sure I understand your second question. The output of `println(myList)` simply redirects to the method `toString()` of `List`, which (through a few more indirections), prints the string `"List"` followed by the elements in parentheses. That's all.

Comment: Was it actually that important in the language design to save two bytes and call this class `::` rather than what the programmer writes to use it - ``List``, and use a different type ``Nil`` for an empty List?